# ons-button onclick not Executing Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am building a mobile app and I'm using Angular JS for my UI.

There is an href element that executes a javascript whenever it is clicked. The problem is that the onclick event is not executing the function placed inside it, but if I put the function implementation directly inside the onclick event of the href element, it gets executed i.e. if I put alert('Alert!!'); in the onclick event, it gets executed but if I call the function callAlertFunc() which also performs alert, it doesn't get executed. what could be the problem?

My Codes are below.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<title>xxxxx</title>  
<!-- Stylesheets--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mapsed.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/fonts.css"/>
<!-- Stylesheets--> 
<!-- Scripts-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/service-integrate.js"></script>
<!-- Scripts-->
<script>
     function callAlertFunc()
     {
        alert('Alert!!');
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
      <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
      </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Get Details</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <ons-row style="padding: 0">
    <ons-col align="center">

    <ons-list>


    </ons-list>

    </ons-col>
  </ons-row>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="center"> <br>
    <input class="text-input" type="text" modifier="large" name="id" placeholder="id">
    <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="hrefID" onclick="callAlertFunc();">
     <ons-button class="home-btn" modifier="large">Get Details</ons-button>
        </a>

    <br></div>

     <div class="center" id="DetailsDiv"> <br>
     <u> Details</u>
     <br>
      <p class="service-data">Status: </p>
     <br>

     </div>
     </ons-page>
     </ons-navigator>



      </body>

       </html>
```

Comment: Does the js function get called? A console.log() could give a hint.

Comment: How this is related with AngularJS?